# Google cloud functions codes

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I’m using cloud function as backend server and i have permitted access to all users as invoker, does that mean anyone on internet have access to my backend codes?

Thank you,

Comment: Review the documentation on the Invoker role. No, users cannot access your Function code. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles

Comment: Nice to hear that, Thank you.

Comment: But anyone with your function endpoint can invoke it. And, for example make a loop to call it indefinitely  and you will pay for the processing. Think to secure your endpoint if you open it broadly on the wild internet!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @John Hanley mentions The Cloud function invoker role has only the permission to call to the function.

This means the cloud function will be callable by anyone on Internet.

On the other hand your code will not be accessible, as viewing the code is only allowed to Project Owners, Editors and cloud functions Admin and developer.

If you want to verify the exact access of each role for cloud functions you can visit [Cloud Functions IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/iam/roles) where you can see the exact permissions on each role.